# Assign multiple data to a variable in sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to assign multiple values to a variable from a SELECT statement in a stored procedure.
The code goes like this

```
DECLARE @ProjectExecutionPlanId INT=NULL

SELECT @ProjectExecutionPlanId = (SELECT [ID] FROM [dbo].[ProjectExecutionPlan] 
                                  WHERE ProjectDetailID=@PID)
```

`@PID` in the input to the stored procedure.

The `SELECT` statement returns multiple values. So I am getting error.

Comment: which of those multiple values do you want to set in  `@ProjectExecutionPlanId`

Comment: What is the error? Perhaps you need to add `TOP 1` to the inner select, or try and understand why you are getting multiple values.

Comment: I can't add TOP 1.I need all the IDs from ProjectExecutionPlan table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is based on your comment:

> I want to delete multiple rows from the ProjectExecutionPlanExecution
>   table which is dependent on ProjectExecutionPlan table.There are
>   multiple plans in ProjectExecutionPlan table. So I will get multiple
>   IDs

```
Delete From ProjectExecutionPlanExecution 
Where ProjectExecutionPlanId In (SELECT [ID]
                                 FROM [dbo].[ProjectExecutionPlan] 
                                 WHERE ProjectDetailID=@PID)
```

Or

```
Delete pe From ProjectExecutionPlanExecution pe
Join ProjectExecutionPlan p On pe.ProjectExecutionPlanID = p.ID
WHERE p.ProjectDetailID=@PID
```